# блок прыгает при загрузке

Tags: html, css, css3

Помогите найти причину того, что блок при загрузке на мобильной версии прыгает. Сначала он влево, а потом перемещается в центр. Нужно чтобы сразу был по центру.
Посмотреть можно здесь: https://spectech33.ru/
Интересует этот блок: http://prntscr.com/kr5u3g

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно осмотрите свои медиа запросы.
Чтобы такого не было пропишите масштабирование данных изображений, в условии под которые попадают мобильные устройства.

Также у вас есть еще вот проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы мобильную версию смотрели?